# Nothing happens when Build and Push IoT Edge Solution

Tags: azure, docker, visual-studio-code, docker-container, azure-iot-edge

I try to build and push my module to my iot edge device. I am following this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/tutorial-c-module

At the step **Build and push your solution**, when I right-click on the `deployment.template.json`, nothing happens. It should have an output in the  integrated terminal but nothing.

Obviously I have the `Azure IoT Edge` extension installed, with Docker and `iotedgehubdev`. And I am successfully logged in my container repository (azurecr.io).

When I look for my image in my repository, there is nothing (obviously, the image wasn't even built..). Really nothing happens, it's like if the button doen't work..

Do you know what could be the problem ? What do I need to check ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you see the context menu "Build and Push IoT Edge solution" when right-click the context menu?
After you click the menu, the log should be in the Terminal named "Azure IoT Edge". Besides, please make sure your deployment.template.json has no error. You can open and check whether there is "red line" marking as error.

Comment: I do see the "Build and Push" option, it's when I click on it that nothing happens. I have no error in the json file